# How to run an ant build.xml from grunt?

Tags: java, xml, ant, gruntjs

Is it possible to run an ant script with grunt and if yes - how? At the moment our eclipse project contains a build.xml file which concats and minifies some css and js files. I want to combine it with a grunt watcher but during my researches I couldn't find a grunt plugin which could run xml ant scripts.

So within my Gruntfile.js there would be a Grunt Watch task like this:

```
watch: {
        dev:{
            files: [
                //my_files
                ...
            ],  
            tasks: ['<some task that runs the build.xml ant script>'],
            options : { 
                nospawn : true                  
            }
        },
}
```

I also could configure another minifying task with grunt without any problems but because other people haven't configured grunt on their computers I would like to use what already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution (for Windows):

requirements: JAVA JDK

I installed ant for windows: https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

copied the downloaded files into a directory and set the paths.

Then I used the Grunt [Exec Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-exec):

Within the Gruntfile.js the configuration is that simple:

```
exec: {
    'run_build_script': 'cd <navigate to the build script directory> && ant'
},
```